# Yii activerecord and pagination count() slow query

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii

So basicly the problem is in query `SELECT COUNT(*)` which executed in `calculateTotalItemCount` function in activedataprovider. As i understood it needed for pagination for `$itemcount` variable. The problem is this query slow for big tables. For my ~30m table it executes 5 seconds.
So there are 2 ways to solve this problem:
1. Disable pagination (`'pagination'=>'false'`) and write own pagination.
2. Rewrite AR count function.

I dont have enough experience/knowledge to acomplish this. 
Maybe some one had same issues before and can share his solution.

Atleast for `totalItemCount` we can use `EXPLAIN SELECT *`. Its way more faster.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: in your count query do you have any conditions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a "cheaper" query in raw SQL than the one that active records create automatically, you can also query manually (e.g. through DAO) and set the `totalItemCount` on your data provider:

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*)...')->queryScalar();
$provider = new CActiveDataProvider('SomeModel', array(
    'totalItemCount' => $count,
    'criteria' => $criteria,
    ...
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Michael you saved me alot of time. 30914676 results page loads 0.13s now instead of 10 seconds with pagination.

Comment: Maybe you can explain howto implement this cheaper count() version for search in gridview() in model->search() function. Thanks.

Comment: @ineersa Not sure if i understand: You said it works, so what are you missing? Just use the above in your `search()` method. You need to build the `count` SQL manually from your search attributes. There's no rule what "cheaper" exactly means: It depends on your DB schema. But your question implies that in some situations you are able to supply a SQL statement that performs better than the auto-created `COUNT` from Yii. It's up to you to find out, when that is the case and how to build it.

Comment: Thank you Michael. I just rewrite search() method for my needs and it works great now. I know that AR is bad for big databases but wanna use dataprovider as well. Will try with CSQLDataprovider next time. Anyway why use such slow query as default.